# R Shiny error on ubuntu: R --no-save --slave -f \/opt\/shiny-server\/R\/SockJSAdapter\.R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm sporadically getting the following error on my R Shiny app. This didn't happen when I only had one shiny app, but now that I am running multiple apps, it happens a lot. The page begins to load, but my leaflet maps don't load and I get a "disconnected from server" message on the screen and this error in the log:

-su: line 1: 27382 Killed                  R --no-save --slave -f /opt/shiny-server/R/SockJSAdapter.R

or this:

Execution halted

Here's an example of a shiny app that's having this problem:

http://www.readingmadrid.com:3838/mnt/

Sometimes I can look at the running sessions and kill them (ps aux | grep R) but that doesn't always work--for example, right now, there are no processes running and my app still isn't working.

Here's my setup:

```
Ubuntu 16.4
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth"
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Shiny Server v1.5.8.921
Node.js v8.11.3
```

Memory:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1971         525         849          32         595        1212
Swap:           999         475         524
```

I tried rebooting the server and restarting Shiny, to no avail. Any ideas as to what the problem could be or how to troubleshoot further?

Comment: It seems a code error as indicated by the websocket connection being closed (it has been closed gracefully, so u can disregard other issues), look at the log file for shiny. It should be generated at run-time (when you access the app) and should be under `ShinyApps/log'

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what's showing up in log/shiny-server:

-su: line 1: 27382 Killed R --no-save --slave -f /opt/shiny-server/R/SockJSAdapter.R

Is there another log? This app works with no errors sometimes, so I know there aren't other problems.

Comment: You need an `Application Error Logs`, see this article where it should be https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003717168-Shiny-Server-Error-Logs

Comment: Thanks, all I see in the application log are entries like this:


[2020-07-08T12:11:07.433] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes

[2020-07-08T12:13:17.120] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.8.921 (Node.js v8.11.3) 

[2020-07-08T12:13:17.123] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf" 

[2020-07-08T12:13:17.201] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on http://[::]:3838